# How to "free" variable after end of the function?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

what is the right way to free an allocated memory after executing function in C (via malloc)? I need to alloc memory, use it somehow and return it back, than I have to free it.

```
char* someFunction(char* a, char* b) {
   char* result = (char*)malloc(la + 2 * sizeof(char));
   ...
   return result;
}
```

Comment: `char *str = someFunction(a, b); useitsomehow(str); free(str);`

Comment: Well, this means that I will return the pointer, which is avaible to free as "str" because it is now the exactly same pointer?

Comment: @JaxCze: Yes, also I would not call it "exactly the same pointer". It is a different (pointer) variable with exactly the same value, i.e. pointing to the same object.

Comment: If you return memory that the caller has to free (and if you can't avoid this), then you should at least make this clear with a comment like: "The caller is responsible for freeing the returned memory".

Comment: You don't free a *variable*, you free some *pointer* (which sits in a variable, or is returned by some function or expression). Be aware of [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing). You need to define and document *conventions* about who and when a pointer should be freed. Some tools (e.g. [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)...) might help to find [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `free`. In your case, it will be:

```
char* result = malloc(la + 2 * sizeof(char));
...
free (result);
```

Also, if you're returning allocated memory, like `strdup` does, the caller of your function has to free the memory. Like:

```
result = somefunction ();
...
free (result);
```

---

If you're thinking of freeing it after returning it, that is not possible. Once you `return` something from the function, it automatically gets terminated.

Comment: This code snippet looks so sketchy, I hope there are no misunderstandings: You should **NOT** `free` the memory before returning it!

Answer (score 6):

In the code that called `someFunction`.

You also have to make clear in the documentation (you have that, right?!), that the **caller** has to call `free`, after finished using the return value.

Answer (score 3):

If you return allocated memory, then it is the caller responsibility to free it.

```
char *res;
res = someFunction("something 1", "something 2");
free(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you `return` it to calling function , then just `free` the pointer in calling function.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that the returned value is not needed in the calling function and the function is called due to its side effects then you can just write

```
free( someFunction( p, q ) );
```

Comment: I didn't mean that like this, but this tip will be useful for me :) thank you